# Using Application Insights to track Url

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-application-insights

I would like create a deep link for promotional purposes that redirects to the home page but that can be used to track how many sessions were iniated from that initial link using Application Insights.

Is it possible to use Application Insights to identity the Url that initiated the session and is this a valid use of Application Insights?

```
routes.MapRoute("Home", string.Empty, new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" })
                    .MapRoute("MyPromo","MyPromo", new { controller = "Home", action="Index" })
                    .MapRoute(
                        "default",
                        "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, that is possible and valid.

The technical details would be up to how you implemented your site/controller/etc.

If application insights is enabled and collecting incoming requests (for asp.net and core it usually is), then the url that initiated the session would have been that inbound request.  and generally, asp.net is also handling session ids as well, so you could write queries that identify the first request in any given session.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In terms of design, do you think it would be better to implement this using routes (as above) or separate controllers?

Comment: that part i don't have a specific opinion on, that really depends on what you're doing.